# ¿Cómo puedo llenar un progressbar mientras se completa una línea de código?

Tags: java, netbeans, jvm

Tengo un programa que recibe PDFs muy pesados. Cuando alcanza cierta línea del código, que es la que carga el PDF, la JVM se bloquea. Para "solventar" esto, metí el código en un worker para que lo haga sin que se bloquee el programa, pero me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer para que mientras acaba de ejecutarse la línea, se llenando un progressbar. ¿Cómo podría hacer esto? Este es mi código:

```
        // Worker
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        ScheduledFuture<?> sf = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            // Documentos
            File f;
            PDDocument docu = null;
            PDDocument clone = null;    
                
            try{
                // Recoger ruta de entrada y salida de dos textField
                String inputRoute = textFieldInput.getText();
                String outputRoute = textFieldOutput.getText();

                f = new File(inputRoute);

                // ESTA línea es la que tarda en completar su acción.
                docu = PDDocument.load(f);

                // A partir de aquí, el programa realiza acciones con el PDF cargado en la 
                //línea anterior
                clone = new PDDocument();

                Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
                splitter.setStartPage(1);          

                List<PDDocument> lst = splitter.split(docu);
                              
                for(PDDocument doc: lst){
                    clone.addPage(doc.getPage(0)); 
                }               

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hecho");
```

Answer (score 1):

Para actualizar un `progressbar` mientras se carga el PDF, debes utilizar un hilo separado `(worker thread)` que se encargue de cargar el documento y al mismo tiempo actualizar el `progressbar`. A continuación, te muestro cómo podrías hacerlo:

Tienes que agregar un `JProgressBar` al `GUI` (interfaz gráfica de usuario) y configúralo, luego, crea una clase que implemente la interfaz `Runnable`. En esta clase, coloca el código que se encarga de cargar el PDF y actualizar el `progressbar`.

Te dejo por aquí el código:

```
public class PDFLoader implements Runnable {

    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    private File file;
    private PDDocument docu;

    public PDFLoader(JProgressBar progressBar, File file) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            docu = PDDocument.load(file);
            // Aquí podrías agregar cualquier código adicional que necesites
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public PDDocument getPDDocument() {
        return docu;
    }
}
```

Luego modifica el código del `worker` para que cree una instancia de la clase `PDFLoader` y la ejecute en un hilo separado. Mientras se carga el PDF, actualiza el `progressbar` según el progreso.

Por ejemplo:

```
SwingWorker<Void, Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        PDFLoader loader = new PDFLoader(progressBar, file);
        Thread thread = new Thread(loader);
        thread.start();

        while (thread.isAlive()) {
            // Actualiza el progressbar en función del progreso
            int progress = (int) ((float) loader.getPDDocument().getCurrentAccessPermission().getMaxPermissionValue() / PDFDocument.USER_ACCESS_PERMISSION * 100);
            publish(progress);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
        // Actualiza el progressbar en la GUI
        progressBar.setValue(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        // Aquí podrías agregar cualquier código adicional que necesites
    }
};

worker.execute();
```

En resumen, lo que hace este código es ejecutar el `PDFLoader` en un hilo separado y actualizar el `progressbar` en la `GUI` mientras se carga el documento. En el método `doInBackground()` del `SwingWorker`, se actualiza el `progressbar` cada 100 mili segundos (puedes ajustar este valor según tus necesidades) y se espera a que termine la carga del documento. Una vez que el documento está cargado, el método `done()` se ejecuta y puedes agregar cualquier código adicional que necesites.

Comment: Hola, gracias por su respuesta. Ya lo he implementado pero tengo un problema en el Worker. En la línea donde se crea el int progress, no me reconoce el método "getMaxPermissionValue() ni "PDFDocument.USER_ACCESS_PERMISSION". En su lugar he utilizado "int progress = (int)((float) loader.getPDDocument().getCurrentAccessPermission().getPermissionBytes());" pero también me he dado cuenta de que lo que hay dentro del While no se está ejecutando y la barra no se mueve... Pero la acción de cargar el PDF y tal sí lo hace

Comment: Lo del while se ejecuta pero int progress no toma ningún valor ya que las funciones que se usan no están disponibles, por lo tanto la barra no se mueve

Comment: Hola???????????

Comment: Gracias por nada.